# Color saturation cm 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, screen, color, nvidia-shield

I have the nvidia shield k1 tablet. It's running cyanogenmod 13 nightly release. On the stock os there was options for color management. Is there any options for this on cm 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage color temperature under Settings - Display - LiveDisplay. Other than that there's no built-in option.

[image]

If the kernel supports it, some kernel management apps can also fine-tune color, although that's not universal across devices.